# Can't figure out how to scrape Google's search results using PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape Google search results using PHP.

I tried using @file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test) but it does not work. It only works with http://www.google.com.

I tried using curl instead. Here's my function:

```
function my_fetch($url,$user_agent='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
5.01; Windows NT 5.0)')  { 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/'); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $result;  }

$googleContent = my_fetch("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test");
echo $googleContent;
```

The result is

```
302 Moved
The document has moved here.
```

With a link to here: http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dtest

Is there any way to crawl the search results using PHP without having to learn the API?

Comment: I think learning the API is a lot more viable.

Comment: Scraping Google search results is against their [TOS](https://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html). Use the [Custom Search API](https://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) instead.

Comment: The current search API is covered at http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html and needs an API key. As search companies ultimately want to make money, they don't make search result pages easy to scrape.

Comment: Now it show the correct result, try it....

Comment: Ashok, you say now it shows the correct result. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Using the Search API is not useful for getting accurate rankings and the amount of data is heavily restricted, even the quite expensive commercial sort is kinda useless for a larger amount of data. Regarding the TOS, you do not accept the TOS by accessing Google and you can reject it in a written statement if you accepted it before (like when using a Google account) not that it plays a role, if you do not cause trouble Google will not hunt you for scraping them. There is a opensource PHP project at http://scraping.compunect.com which scrapes  Google reliable. I guess my answer comes too late:)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is Google does a redirect. You need to add

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to scrape? There are numerous ways of getting SERPS without breaking Google's TOS.

I've used RSS feeds from Search engines in the past - I think you can add a date filter so you don't end up with the same results reach time.

Comment: I am trying to scrape the ratings. I don't know any way of getting the rating data using the API or RSS feeds.